# how to corner Radius some edges in IBInspectable in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, cornerradius, ibinspectable

so here is the code that is working well

```
let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:viewToRound.bounds,
                    byRoundingCorners:[.topRight, .bottomLeft],
                    cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 20, height:  20))

let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()

maskLayer.path = path.cgPath
viewToRound.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

But I need to use this many times in my codes So I created the class for view and want to use this in IBInspectable to be optional each edges to change the corners radiuses in story Board so I used this But it does not shown in story board

```
@IBInspectable
open var cornerEdges: CGSize {
    get {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:self.bounds,
                                byRoundingCorners:[.topRight, .bottomLeft],
                                cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 20, height:  20))

        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()

        maskLayer.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = maskLayer
        return maskLayer.path as! CGSize
    }
    set(value) {
        maskLayer.path = value
    }
}
```

so what should I do for doing this in my codes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just Change your class to `@IBDesignable`  to see in storyboard

Like

```
@IBDesignable // Add this to your class
class PlusButton: AnyUIClass { }
```

You can see it in storyboard

[image]

### how to Get corners and radius from storybaord

Here is a sample code

```
@IBInspectable
open var cornerEdges: CGSize = CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)
@IBInspectable  var topLeft: Bool = true
@IBInspectable  var topRight: Bool = true
@IBInspectable  var bottomLeft: Bool = true
@IBInspectable  var bottomRight: Bool = true

override func awakeFromNib() {

    var options = UIRectCorner()
    if topLeft {
       options =  options.union(.topLeft)
    }
    if topRight {
       options =  options.union(.topRight)
    }
    if bottomLeft {
      options =  options.union(.bottomLeft)
    }
    if bottomRight {
      options =  options.union(.bottomRight)
    }


    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:self.bounds,
                            byRoundingCorners:options,
                            cornerRadii: self.cornerEdges)

    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    maskLayer.path = path.cgPath
    self.layer.mask = maskLayer
}
```

Comment: I will see this error after using your code 
Use of unresolved identifier 'maskLayer'

Comment: @SaeedRahmatolahi That is  the same code you have posted in question .

Comment: @SaeedRahmatolahi I suggest you to don't use get - set block here instead you can  apply mask path in awakeFromNib method

Comment: I have a class that do many things and use it many times in my app I want to use this in that class so I need to just use this as I mentioned in the question

Comment: @SaeedRahmatolahi Okay What are the dynamic values I  mean that  required 
on runtime ? like corner radius

Comment: edge corners for example I can set right top corner - left top corner - left bottom corner and right bottom corner so I need four edges corner in story board

Comment: @SaeedRahmatolahi You can't take Drop down there. You  have to create 4 Bool property that will be used to identify which corner need to apply the radius

Comment: ok please tell me what for one corner I will do that for the rest corners

Comment: that's not exactly what I wanted But this will help me for now thank you

Comment: @SaeedRahmatolahi What you  need then ? As I told you , You can't have corners in to the storyboard it is not supported this is best solution known :D=)

Comment: no this is good thanks I wanted to do corners for each edges different for example top edge corner Radius 10 and top right corner Radius 5 and in story board don't see the width and height just see one number to change the corner But this is working thanks

Comment: @SaeedRahmatolahi I wonder this is possible or not will update you if found anything :)

Comment: thanks man I think it's possible to get one number in story board and use it in the class for both width and height

Comment: I have changed the open var to Int 
open var cornerEdges : Int = 0
and defined new variable in codes 
var edge : CGSize = CGSize(width: cornerEdges, height: cornerEdges)
and use  edge value in every where instead of cornerEdges But this will show me error Value of type 'RoundButton' has no member 'edge'

Comment: I have found that is the solution 
I will answer my question thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

so if you want to change both height and width edge corner you can use @PrashantTukadiya answer But if you want to just set a number for corner you can use this code

```
 @IBInspectable
open var cornerEdges : CGFloat = 0
@IBInspectable  var topLeft: Bool = false
@IBInspectable  var topRight: Bool = false
@IBInspectable  var bottomLeft: Bool = false
@IBInspectable  var bottomRight: Bool = false
 override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    var options = UIRectCorner()
    if topLeft {
        options =  options.union(.topLeft)
    }
    if topRight {
        options =  options.union(.topRight)
    }
    if bottomLeft {
        options =  options.union(.bottomLeft)
    }
    if bottomRight {
        options =  options.union(.bottomRight)
    }


    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:self.bounds,
                            byRoundingCorners:options,
                            cornerRadii: CGSize(width: self.cornerEdges, height: self.cornerEdges))

    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    maskLayer.path = path.cgPath
    self.layer.mask = maskLayer
}
```

Comment: Good job !! here

Comment: thanks for your helping now one more thing that is not important is how to change each edges corner different from the others

Comment: so there is a problem here after using this class in my codes in iPhone every things working well but in iPad the right top corner does not work @PrashantTukadiya